# Java - Program that checks if the user's serial code format is valid or not

Tags: java, string, format

I'm trying to create program that will ask the user to enter serial numbers in a specific format and the program will verify if the codes are valid or not.

The format should be 2 numbers, followed by a dash, 4 numbers, a dot, then 4 numbers and 2 letters (note: letters accepted are only a,b,c).

Example of valid format:

```
31-0001.2341ac    
00-9999.0001cb
```

If the length of the string is longer/shorter than the format (14 characters total length) it should display invalid. Same thing, if other characters were used it will also say invalid.

This is the code that I have done so far. Im not sure how I can achieve the exact specified format. Hopefully someone can help..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SerialCheck{
        public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many serial numbers would you like to check: ");
        int length = sc.nextInt();
        int valid = 0;

        String[] sSerials = new String[length];

        for (int nCtr = 0; nCtr < length; nCtr++){
            System.out.print ("Enter Serial " + (nCtr+1) + ": ");
            sSerials[nCtr] = sc.next();
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The following were added: ");
            for(int nCtr = 0; nCtr < length; nCtr++){
            System.out.println(sSerials[nCtr]);
        }

        System.out.println();
            for(int nCtr = 0; nCtr < length; nCtr++){
                for (int x = 0; x < sSerials[nCtr].length(); x++){
                    char c = sSerials[nCtr].charAt(x);

                if((sSerials[nCtr].charAt(x)!='a') || 
                   (sSerials[nCtr].charAt(x)!='b') || 
                   (sSerials[nCtr].charAt(x)!='c') ||
                   (sSerials[nCtr].charAt(x)!='-') ||
                   (sSerials[nCtr].charAt(x)!='.')){
                    valid--;
                } 
                else{
                    valid++;
                }
            }
            if (valid < 0 && sSerials[nCtr].length() != 14){
                System.out.println("The address is invalid.");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The address is valid.");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I frequently post answers saying "don't use regular expressions". But in this case: use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). They are the right tool for this job.

```
boolean isValid = sSerials[nCtr].matches(
    "[0-9]{2}"        // Match 2 digits
        + "-"         // Then a dash
        + "[0-9]{4}"  // Then 4 digits
        + "\\."       // Then a dot (which must be escaped)
        + "[0-9]{4}"  // Then 4 digits
        + "[abc]{2}"  // Then 2 a, b or c.
```

This regex is split up simply to explain the parts of it. You can write the string literal on one line:

```
boolean isValid =
     sSerials[nCtr].matches("[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\\.[0-9]{4}[abc]{2}");
```

Comment: Thanks it works! :) Just a follow up question. Is it also possible to use regular expressions to add characters in a string format?  
    Let's say the user's serial code was determined by the program to be invalid because its length is shorter so the program will then append leading zeros to meet its required length to make the serial valid?

Comment: Example, Input : 32-1234.4ab will be converted to 32-1234.0004ab, filling it with zeros to meet the length

Comment: You can for some types of replacement, but not that. It'd be much easier just to use `substring`: Sth like `str.substring(0, 8) + "0000".substring(0, 14-str.length()) + str.substring(8)`. Sorry, haven't checked the numbers in that, but hopefully gives you the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some websites or utility like [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) which helps building you regular expression for required string(Seqial number for your product).
Then use [java.util.regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) package for identifying them,

The link[java.util.regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) given will expose you all the functions using which you can filter perticular type of string.